# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException But I am not removing

Tags: java, recursion, concurrentmodification, continue

My below recursive function throws a ConcurrentModificationException on the 'continue' statement. I looked at a few posts on ConcurrentModificationException and all of the problems seem to be with removing an element from an element, but I am not removing any element in my function.

My function is below :

```
    public static void getRootedTreeHelper(Node n, boolean[] marked, String spacing){ 

        System.out.println(spacing + "in helper with " + n.getId());
        marked[n.getId()] = true;
        if(n.children.isEmpty())
            return;
        else{
            for(Node child : n.children){
                if(marked[child.getId()])
                    continue; // ConcurrentModificationException is thrown here. 
                else{
                    n.addChild(child);
                    spacing = spacing + "\t";
                    getRootedTreeHelper(child, marked, spacing);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

As requested : The relevant portions of Node Class are shown below

```
public class Node {

    private int id;
    ArrayList<Node> children;

    public Node(int id) {
        this.id = id;
        children = new ArrayList<Node>();
    }

    /**
     * add node n to this node's children
     * @param n
     */
    public void addChild(Node n) {
        children.add(n);
    }

    // getters and setters()
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Edit solved :
Rather than using a for each loop to iterate through all the children, I use a for loop.

Comment: Show your Node class

Comment: What type is n.children? Can you add the stacktrace?

Comment: The same `ConcurrentModificationException` can also happen when you add to a list while iterating.

Comment: Relevant parts of Node class are shown now.
@flob, n.children returns an array list of Node

Comment: Question, why did you feel you needed to create your own `Node` class and not use a subclass of `org.w3c.dom.Node`?

Comment: You show the exception being thrown on the `continue` statement, which doesn't make sense. Are you sure it's not being thrown when you call `n.addChild`?

Comment: @hfontanez school project

Comment: @Rohan, you will have to use two Nodes, the original and a new Node.  You will have to make modifications to the new node and iterate over the original node.

Comment: @hfontanez there is always a good reason as `org.w3c.dom.Node` is just an interface, is dependent to a `org.w3c.dom.Document` (we are speaking XML?), has quite a lot of potentially unneeded methods, has way to many implementations, might not fit his special usecase,  ... besides from needing a special node implementation for any kind of tree or graph.. :-)

Comment: @flob "there is always a good reason"? You probably mean "there could be good reasons", but definitely not always. Otherwise, there would be no need for the subclasses `org.w3c.dom`provides for it. I was merely trying to engage the OP, that's all. I wasn't trying to arise a philosophical discussion about the matter.

Comment: @hfontanez I took into account the current context and that the poster had quite a small node class which didn't seem to need all that functionality.. So let me rephrase it: If you are not implementing the W3C Dom, you can always find a good reason not to use `org.w3c.dom.Node` as a starting point for your node. Even if you take a look at the Java Class Library there are many other implementations of a node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `ConcurrentModificationException` Javadoc:

> Note that this exception does not always indicate that an object has 
>   been concurrently modified by a *different* thread.  (...) For
>   example, if a thread modifies a collection directly while it is
>   iterating over the collection with a fail-fast iterator, the iterator 
>   will throw this exception.

The bug is adding a child into the collection while also iterating over it.

The fault is only *detected* by the iterator, when it is incremented in the `for` loop.

Comment: This is the case. The problem is that, because he created his own rudimentary `Node` class, he doesn't have this facility.

Comment: This can be caused with any [failing] re-entrant access while iterating; threads are not required.

Answer (score 4):

If you take a look at the `ArrayList`s implementation of an Iterator, it shows that during `Iterator.next()` it checks if the size of the collection has changed.

```
if (i >= elementData.length)
  throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
```

Even using a synchronized version with `Collections.synchronizedList(n.children)` wouldn't help as it still uses the same Iterator.

So if you need to have concurrent access that modifies the collection you have some choices:

- use `Iterator.remove()` to remove the current element,
- use a version that allows concurrent modification like a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` or `ConcurrentLinkedDeque` or
- use another `List` for writing changes than for iterating.

You could try a `LinkedList` - i haven't read the source fully but a quick glance at its `Iterator` seems like it is immune to additions while iterating.